# Display a message how many rows of a MySQL table are affected after a query

Tags: python, mysql

> Write a Python program to increase the price of product whose name contains alphabet 'a' in it. Also display a message how many records are updated.

I have solved the first part of the question using LIKE operator but I'm finding difficulty in the second part

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM2Zv.png)

```
c.execute("select Product_name from products") 
b=c.fetchall() 
con.commit() 
count=0 
for i in b:     
     if "a" in i:         
         count+=1 
print(count)
```

OUTPUT:
0

But the rows have been affected

[Modified table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqxVh.png)

I have tried the `mysql_affected_rows()` but this too shows error so I want to keep the program simple and use python loops for counting

Comment: The affected rows is definitely something you should be querying from the cursor or execution after submitting the sql. If you wait, requery, and count results there is no guarantee that another process didn't sneak in and make table changes between your two executions. If you are stuck with the route you are currently taking, then I would think `SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE product_name like '%a%';` would be cleaner than shoveling an unknown number of records over the wire merely to loop and count them locally.